# Почему в переменной count будет значение 3?

Tags: javascript

```js
var count = 3;

function doSomething() {
  count = 5;

  if (true) {
    return count + 4;
  }
  function count() {}
}

doSomething();

console.log(count); // 3
```

Comment: Потому что область видимости.

Comment: Потому что внутри `doSomething` `count` является функцией и перекрывает внешнюю переменную

Comment: @АндрейNOP `count` *сначала* является функцией

Answer (score 1):

Интерпретатор поднимает объявления функции на подобие этого
`function count() {}`. ([О поднимании объявленной функции на MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function#%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8)). Такое объявление создает переменную `count` в локальной области видимости. Это значит, что ваш пример идентичен такому:

```
function doSomething() {
    function count() {}
    count = 5;

    if (true) {
        return count + 4;
    }
}
```

И далее `count = 5` и `return count + 4` работает с локальной переменной `count`, перезаписывая присвоенную ей функцию.

По этому глобальная переменная `count` при вызове функции `doSomething()` остается нетронутой.